# CM Storm Xornet remapping sensitivity buttons possible?

Tags: autohotkey

I recently got the CM Xornet gaming mouse and was wondering if it was possible to remap the two sensitivity buttons on top to behave similar to the two buttons on the side (mouse4 and 5) using AHK. I have checked on various sites for an answer, but without any luck. Any help would be very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Launch an AHK script using the [keyboard hook](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_InstallKeybdHook.htm) -> Double click its tray icon -> Menu **View** - **Key history** -> Press the desired key -> Refresh -> Look for the key name / scan code. Scan codes can be used as described [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: Tried it out but with no luck, it does not register. Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: My mistake, try `#InstallMouseHook` instead.